# Linux Storage Size is Full.. but how...?

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage

I only have small php files on this server, and it fits 80gb. where is all the space being consumed? Its not sustainable if it never clears out the temp space. How could I resolve this and clear out what might be consuming all the space on the server. could it be logs?

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/xvda1             79G   79G  4.6M 100% /

tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

This shows all the size is being consumed in var/log/httpd~

```
 du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 10
 du: cannot access `/proc/1635/task/1635/fd/4': No such file or directory
 du: cannot access `/proc/1635/task/1635/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
 du: cannot access `/proc/1635/fd/4': No such file or directory
 du: cannot access `/proc/1635/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
 82313432        /
 81281820        /var
 80612296        /var/log
 80568212        /var/log/httpd
 73591608        /var/log/httpd/access_log
 6949756 /var/log/httpd/access_log-20130818
 784468  /usr
 428232  /var/spool
 428188  /var/spool/mail
 428184  /var/spool/mail/root
```

How can I clear this out and prevent it from happening in the future?

Comment: You should ask this question on Server Fault, instead of Stack Overfow. And you'd want to check /var/log, it's a usual suspect when you suddenly run out of space.

Comment: thanks Kamituel. it looked like it was the logs.

Comment: yeah, I figured. Just note, that logs usually do not grow that large quickly - if it's httpd, look at this logs before deleting them to see what's wrong with Apache. Otherwise you'll run out of space again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try to clean some space, for example truncate some log files in /var/log
and after that check which are the largest folders by `du -a / | sort -n -r | head -n 10`

Comment: It looks like all the space is within the var/log/httpd ~ with access_log- 
whats the best way to clear that, and then prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: are there a lot of access_logs file or just one large? If its just one you can truncate it be echo ''>/var/log/http/large_access_log, if there are too many files you have to change log rotate options... what are your operating system?

Comment: Vladimir, its 6949756 /var/log/httpd/access_log-20130818 (which I 'rm', removed) and then there is
73591608        /var/log/httpd/access_log

Comment: is there a way to prevent httpd/apache from storing log data? Usually I never look at it. just seems like could cause issues in the future.

Comment: `echo ''>/var/log/httpd/access_log`, but before that it's not bad idea to see what is the most frequent content, so you can prevent the same situation in future. 73Gb access log for 2 months is not very common

Comment: yeah. it was showing a bunch of 404 errors.
If I deleted "rm" /var/log/httpd/access_log, would that cause any issues. I'm sure it would just create a new one from scratch again right?

Comment: ah yeah. the echo probably the best way to do that. thanks

Comment: you can stop access logs by set them to /dev/null in most cases just edit AccessLog to (AccessLog /dev/null) line in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf or apache2.conf or in vhost's file

Comment: Can I comment this out inside httpd/conf 
CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
would that stop running access_logs?

Comment: yes, it will, if there no another AccessLog line in some virtualhost's file. Try it